# Character array seems same but not the same

Tags: c++, arrays

In the following code, though the strings are the same, I get output as "string are different"

What's the logic?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

 main(void)
{
 char str1[30]="India",str2[30]="India";
 cout<<"str1 address :"<<str1<<endl;
 cout<<"str2 address :"<<str2<<endl;

 if(str1==str2)
    cout<<"strings same"<<endl;
 else

cout<<"strings are different"<<endl;

}
```

Even with `strcmp()`, output is the same, *i.e* "strings are different".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

 main(void)
{
 char str1[30]="India",str2[30]="India";
 cout<<"str1 address :"<<str1<<endl;
 cout<<"str2 address :"<<str2<<endl;

 if(strcmp(str1,str2))
    cout<<"strings same"<<endl;
 else
    cout<<"strings are different"<<endl;

}
```

Comment: `strcmp()` returns `0` if strings are equals else non-zero, and `0` is false condition, thats the reason I used `!` in `if()`. Please read the documentation link I given in my answer. Put some effort to learn.

Answer (score 4):

Because you can't compare C strings like that. I'm not sure about `std::string` (which you should use as this is C++), but when you're using character-arrays you're using the `==` operator on the addresses, which are not the same. Use [`strcmp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) to compare C strings.

**EDIT**: as Mr. Beer noted, you can use the `==` operator on `std::string`, so try changing your strings to:

```
std::string str1 = "India", str2 = "India";
```

Comment: Yes, you can use the `==` operator on std::string.

Answer (score 1):

Their addresses are not same. You are comparing their pointers. 
Their data are same, of which you need something like strcmp().

str1 points to address of first byte of first array.
str2 points to address of first byte of second array. **Which are same only with some compiler optimization.(and this is not %100 possible, may fail after a copy/assignment action)**

Comment: If they are used to initialize **arrays**, then even their addresses won't be the same. With an optimizing compiler, most likely `const char *p1 = "foo"; const char *p2 = "foo";` would work, but it won't work for sure if the string is copied into two different **arrays.**

Answer (score 1):

By comparing char array using `==` in `if(str1==str2)` you are comparing base addresses of two different arrays (that is not same), you should use `if(!strcmp(str1, str2))` to compare strings.

Read: [int strcmp ( const char * str1, const char * str2 );](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/)

> returns Returns an integral value indicating the relationship between the strings:
>     A zero value indicates that both strings are equal.
>     A value greater than zero indicates that the first character that does not match has a greater value in `str1` than in `str2`; And a value less than zero indicates the opposite.